# how to add options to the dynamically added new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm developing a website builder in which i need to add boxes in main section at runtime (by user) and when i click on that boxes, some option related to that box should appear. when i create one div (box) in the main section and click on it, it works fine and options menu appears. but when i add multiple boxes and click on the first box which i added, the first one calls the click function twice, and due to toggle option, the menu box for first box didn't show up. Here's the code, but it doesn't seems to work here (may be jquery-ui js and css libraries issue).

```js
var x_axis = 0; y_axis = 0;
$("#menubutton").mouseover(function(){
 $("#menubutton").css("cursor","pointer");
});
   
// it will create a new div in mainsection div
$("#menubutton").click(function(){
 var totalChildren = $("#mainSection").children().length;
 var id = totalChildren+1;
 $("#mainSection").append("<div id='"+id+"' class='newDiv' style='background-color:white; border:2px solid black; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; left:"+x_axis+"px; top:"+y_axis+"px; z-index:1;'></div>");
     
  $(".newDiv").draggable({
      containment : 'parent',
      opacity: 0.5
  });

  // For editing options of div
  $(".newDiv").click(function(){
      divId = $(this).attr("id");

      $("#optionsMenu").toggle();
      alert(divId);
  });
});
```

```css
#optionsMenu{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: inline-block;
 height: 500px;
 position:absolute;
 right: 10px;
 top:50px;
 z-index: 2;
 padding: 10px;
 display: none;
 background-color: #14C4E4;
}

.buttonStyle{
 border:1px solid green; 
 color: white; 
 background-color:5BDD45; 
 text-align:center; 
 border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
 position: relative;
 left:0px;
 padding: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="button" >
   <span id="menubutton" class="buttonStyle">Add Box</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10" id="mainSection">
   <div style="border:1px solid black; height:400px; position:relative;">
   </div>
  </div>
     
  <div id="optionsMenu">
   <div id="boxOptions" style="z-index:2">
   The options for the box will be shown here!
   </div>
  </div> 
 </body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/44uyxLrh/7/

Comment: Your code requires jquery framework. You add either a source on the left-hand side of the fiddle, or more conveniently in the javascript area click on the cog. In the dropdown > Frameworks & Extensions select jQuery 3.2.1 (or another version). Also in load type set ondomready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the below lines from your code

```
  // For editing options of div
  $(".newDiv").click(function(){
      divId = $(this).attr("id");
      $("#optionsMenu").toggle();
      alert(divId);
  });
```

at every click it creates a duplicate click function that is appending on existing 
`.newDiv`. Which make the Options div to toggle twice or more, which results in options div to be hidden.

Modify your code as below. [**JSFiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/44uyxLrh/9/)

```
var x_axis = 0;
y_axis = 0;
$("#menubutton").mouseover(function() {
    $("#menubutton").css("cursor", "pointer");
});

function toggleOption() {
    divId = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#optionsMenu").toggle();
    alert(divId);
}

// it will create a new div in mainsection div
$("#menubutton").click(function() {
    var totalChildren = $("#mainSection").children().length;
    var id = totalChildren + 1;
    $("#mainSection").append("<div id='" + id + "' class='newDiv' style='background-color:white; border:2px solid black; width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; left:" + x_axis + "px; top:" + y_axis + "px; z-index:1;'></div>");

    $(".newDiv").draggable({
        containment: 'parent',
        opacity: 0.5
    });

    // For editing options of div
    $('.newDiv').off('click', toggleOption);
    $('.newDiv').on('click', toggleOption);

});
```

Comment: thanks for replying. its working, but just one little issue, now i have to double click on the div to show/hide option menu when i add multiple divs, can you look into this?

Comment: sorry i didn't saw the jsfiddle link, its working perfectly.. just what i needed.. thanks a bunch.